# Week Number restarting at 1 every month as per ISO format in Tableau

Tags: date, tableau-api, iso, week-number

I am trying to get week numbers ( resetting  at 1 for each month) as per ISO format for each month in 2019.For example I am interested in getting

**All dates in July 2019: week 1 to 4,**

**All dates in Aug 2019 : week 1 to 4  and so on.**

I first created the calculated field (Week_Number_ISO) to get the overall week number in year 2019.I used the following formula;

**DATEPART('iso-week',[ Date])** which works as intended.

To get the monthly week number I used the following formula

**INT((DATEPART('day',[Created Date])-DATEPART('iso-weekday',[Created Date])+7)/7)+1.**

(Idea was to calculate the date of the first day of each week & then divide by 7 and take the integer part)

As per the ISO format, shouldn't  July 29 to 31st be a part of week 4 for July?But the formula is showing it as week 5 for July 2019.I feel I am missing something in the formula or am missing something about ISO week number resetting at 1 for each month.

Can someone help me?

Here is an example of the dates in July 2019 and the associated week numbers.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would July 28th-July 31st 2019 be considered week 4?

[image: Weeks of July 2019]

Comment: that makes sense, but as an ISO week  always has seven days and does not have t  partial weeks that contain only four or five days, I am confused how it counts last 3 days of July as a separate week

Comment: What is the expected week number for July 31st and for August 1st? The ISO week number was 31, I am not sure what the desired outcome is.

Comment: thanks @Bob makes sense to end last days of July as week 5 and start Aug 1st as week 1